# Converting from an ArrayList[x]byte[] to a byte[] with .toArray?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, type-conversion

I have a number of graphics files that include both images and videos.  I want to store these in an arrayList.  Most files will be images.  Only some will be short low-resolution videos.

I have chosen to use an arrayList of byte[].  The following code is intended to test the steps.
I load the image file into the ArrayList.
I then attempt to write a copy of the enclosed byte[] to a file.  I have successfully used this command before to write a standalone byte[] to a file, so I know it works.

The problem is that I need to read the whole byte array from the ArrayList as an array. I can't figure out how to do that.

I have found the .toArray command in the Java API but I can't figure out the syntax for this case.   The API isn't clear to me.
  I have tried:

```
    byte[] b =  new byte[1000];
    ary[0].toArray(byte[] b);
```

and

```
    ary[0].toArray();
```

but I can't get them to work.

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class testArrayListByteCopy {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Running Array of byte arrays copy test");

        ArrayList < byte[] > ary;  //define the  arrays

        //create an ArrayList with 3x byte[] arrays       
        ary = new ArrayList<byte[]>(3);  
        //load up one of them
        try {
        ary.add(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/home/test1.png")));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    

           // save byte[] into a file
            Path path = Paths.get("/home/testSave.png");
//          The next line fails.  The error message says array expected but arrayList byte[] found.  Illegal start of expression. 
            //Files.write(path, ary[0].toArray()  ,StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
// This line  works based on the answers below.
        Files.write(path, arrayTo.get(0),StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
                System.out.println("Done");
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Wait, you are trying to store **videos** in memory? Do you realize how much space that actually requires?

Comment: The video files are between  50kB and 200kB so storing them in memory isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write `ary.get(0)` instead of `ary[0].toArray()` because the type `ArrayList` is not subscriptable with `[]`. Only builtin array types are (`T[]`).

Comment: Perfect.  I don't know how long it would have taken me to find that nugget of information.  I have just done a search on Java T[ ] and found the generics tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html but that doesn't appear to limit T[ ] to built-in array types.

Comment: What I meant by "builtin-array" types is the `[]` part, that is to say any Java & Custom Class can be grouped in an array of its type. (ex: let's say you have a class named `Foo`, then you can create an array of type `Foo[]` and access it using `[ . ]`, which you cannot do with an `ArrayList<Foo>`.

Comment: Also, make sure to accept the answer so the topic may be closed :)